# (Beginner) C# JSON deserializing troubles

Tags: c#, json, vk

I'm trying my hand at coding a music browser app for the VK social network and I'm having a bit of trouble making API calls to their service.

Essentially, the example JSON response that they give for a certain query on their developer site is pretty significantly different to what my app and browser read when plugging in the query URL directly.

I suppose the issue is that the example query on the site is a LOT easier to implement than the one that's returned in practice, so I'm kind of hoping against hope that I'm missing something obvious so that I don't have to learn to pick apart the JSON response myself and link it to classes (as opposed to using json2csharp)

I'll give you folks an example of the difference that I'm seeing. First the example response provided by the developer site:

```
response: {
count: 3411,
items: [{
id: 18819,
from_id: -41750294,
owner_id: -41750294,
date: 1446984665,
post_type: 'post',
text: 'Various Artists – Resonance / Turncoat
Label: Quarantine Recordings
Catalogue: QRN 2004
Country: U.K.
Release Date: 30 Oct 2015',
attachments: [{
type: 'photo',
photo: {
id: 386477538,
album_id: 212496672,
owner_id: 1881108,
photo_75: 'https://pp.vk.me/...27b/0be4siJV0lY.jpg',
photo_130: 'https://pp.vk.me/...27c/aE3TNi1R2JA.jpg',
photo_604: 'https://pp.vk.me/...27d/4LQ27MVxPX8.jpg',
photo_807: 'https://pp.vk.me/...27e/Z8tJgN8Z3gU.jpg',
photo_1280: 'https://pp.vk.me/...27f/q2HYIQLwxHI.jpg',
width: 1024,
height: 1024,
text: 'QRN2004',
date: 1446984456,
access_key: 'c962ab59cb3915bdf2'
}
}, {
type: 'audio',
audio: {
id: 410724007,
owner_id: 2000374498,
artist: 'Fierce & Dom',
title: 'Resonance',
duration: 322,
date: 1446984665,
url: 'https://psv4.vk.m...CpMuxnT_0RUvJqxxIoZ',
genre_id: 8
}
}, {
type: 'audio',
audio: {
id: 412128187,
owner_id: 2000374305,
artist: 'Fierce & Zero T',
title: 'Turncoat',
duration: 331,
date: 1446984665,
url: 'https://psv4.vk.m...BcWuQ9T3uFA0_MKyuAk',
genre_id: 8
}
}],
post_source: {
type: 'vk'
},
comments: {
count: 1,
can_post: 1
},
likes: {
count: 47,
user_likes: 0,
can_like: 1,
can_publish: 1
},
reposts: {
count: 11,
user_reposted: 0
}
}],
profiles: [],
groups: [{
id: 41750294,
name: 'Neurodeep Community',
screen_name: 'neurodeep_community',
is_closed: 0,
type: 'page',
is_admin: 0,
is_member: 1,
photo_50: 'https://pp.vk.me/...f3d/9tc7nU8eRws.jpg',
photo_100: 'https://pp.vk.me/...f3c/rqliVAMWVNI.jpg',
photo_200: 'https://pp.vk.me/...f3b/Ll62Rn6xmok.jpg'
}]
}
```

And now the response from manually plugging in the url (https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-41750294&offset=1&count=1&filter=owner&extended=1)

```
{"response":{"wall":[3412,{"id":18819,"from_id":-41750294,"to_id":-41750294,"date":1446984665,"post_type":"post","text":"Various Artists – Resonance \/ Turncoat<br>Label: Quarantine Recordings<br>Catalogue: QRN 2004 <br>Country: U.K.<br>Release Date: 30 Oct 2015","attachment":{"type":"photo","photo":{"pid":386477538,"aid":212496672,"owner_id":1881108,"src":"http:\/\/cs627217.vk.me\/v627217108\/1d27c\/aE3TNi1R2JA.jpg","src_big":"http:\/\/cs627217.vk.me\/v627217108\/1d27d\/4LQ27MVxPX8.jpg","src_small":"http:\/\/cs627217.vk.me\/v627217108\/1d27b\/0be4siJV0lY.jpg","src_xbig":"http:\/\/cs627217.vk.me\/v627217108\/1d27e\/Z8tJgN8Z3gU.jpg","src_xxbig":"http:\/\/cs627217.vk.me\/v627217108\/1d27f\/q2HYIQLwxHI.jpg","width":1024,"height":1024,"text":"QRN2004","created":1446984456,"access_key":"02aab51e5ff130f264"}},"attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"pid":386477538,"aid":212496672,"owner_id":1881108,"src":"http:\/\/cs627217.vk.me\/v627217108\/1d27c\/aE3TNi1R2JA.jpg","src_big":"http:\/\/cs627217.vk.me\/v627217108\/1d27d\/4LQ27MVxPX8.jpg","src_small":"http:\/\/cs627217.vk.me\/v627217108\/1d27b\/0be4siJV0lY.jpg","src_xbig":"http:\/\/cs627217.vk.me\/v627217108\/1d27e\/Z8tJgN8Z3gU.jpg","src_xxbig":"http:\/\/cs627217.vk.me\/v627217108\/1d27f\/q2HYIQLwxHI.jpg","width":1024,"height":1024,"text":"QRN2004","created":1446984456,"access_key":"02aab51e5ff130f264"}},{"type":"audio","audio":{"aid":410724007,"owner_id":2000374498,"artist":"Fierce &amp; Dom","title":"Resonance","duration":322,"url":"http:\/\/cs422118.vk.me\/u1881108\/audios\/015b54d160bf.mp3?extra=pwpTdyJOeDJRbnsCJg6aAs4CS0AcoLKR_2--skxAdGqvgP7umh36xc9hbsNQK8OuGX00cDCbiCpMvx2C808Cu8vjwNFN","performer":"Fierce &amp; Dom","genre":8}},{"type":"audio","audio":{"aid":412128187,"owner_id":2000374305,"artist":"Fierce &amp; Zero T","title":"Turncoat","duration":331,"url":"http:\/\/cs422118.vk.me\/u1881108\/audios\/56c37e9c4bac.mp3?extra=AsszsN2Qvcmr5Udr3TKzyDQoDvs1wSnI1bOj1pmcrYkDj0c4McuQF3zaEB3SiX_Tk6gAUtJTTBcW6gFT3rMQj_8JnOJw","performer":"Fierce &amp; Zero T","genre":8}}],"comments":{"count":1},"likes":{"count":48},"reposts":{"count":11}}],"profiles":[],"groups":[{"gid":41750294,"name":"Neurodeep Community","screen_name":"neurodeep_community","is_closed":0,"type":"page","photo":"http:\/\/cs627227.vk.me\/v627227108\/10f3d\/9tc7nU8eRws.jpg","photo_medium":"http:\/\/cs627227.vk.me\/v627227108\/10f3c\/rqliVAMWVNI.jpg","photo_big":"http:\/\/cs627227.vk.me\/v627227108\/10f3b\/Ll62Rn6xmok.jpg"}]}}
```

Fell free to let me know if I'm being dumb and missing something or even if I'm biting off a bit too much for me to chew given my beginner status, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: where you see doc and samples for this?

Comment: The first example is missing a lot of `"`. If you are using Visual Studio, you can Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes (with the URL response in the clipboard). Then use Json.Net to deserialize to that class structure.

Comment: Can you provide the link for the API call?  Are you sure the API call itself is for the exact same method and version?

Comment: @Grundy, justin - The documentation for what I'm trying to do is here: https://vk.com/dev/wall.get

I can't confirm that it's the EXACT same method and version since it doesn't provide me with a link, I had to put that one together based on the template provided here: https://vk.com/dev/api_requests

Thanks crashmstr, I'll give that a shot!

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, what worked was programmatically removing the "{"response":" from the returned string. I don't have the skill to tell you why, but that definitely seems to be what it was getting hung up on!

Answer (score 0):

after 16 December VKontakte api disabled, moreover, they have started to encrypt links
 but isset paid analogues such as [api.xn--41a.ws/](http://api.xn--41a.ws/en/)